# Unable to exit emergency mode

Tags: fsck

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEbB2.jpg)

Ubuntu is entering emergency mode each time I try to boot. I tried to find some fix, after pressing enter when I run the command mount -a and press ctrl + D, Ubuntu boots normally. However it's temporary and I need to run this command each time I need to use Ubuntu. I also tried running the following code in terminal after Ubuntu started normally:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs/v1.43.1/e2fsprogs-1.43.1.tar.gz
tar xzf e2fsprogs-1.43.1.tar.gz
cd e2fsprogs-1.43.1
./configure
make
cd e2fsck/
sudo ./e2fsck -y /dev/sda3
```

The last command didn't run and said sudo  ./e2fsck command not found. I tried running ./sbin/e2fsck but same problem.
Can someone tell me how to exit emergency mode without using the command mount -a each time I use it?

Comment: I tried  running the commands given in this link: https://www.linuxslaves.com/2019/09/how-to-fix-you-are-in-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: What sent you off to doing all that stuff? Did you run a regular fsck first? What happened right before this problem started?

Comment: No, I did not run fsck. Nothing really happened before the problem started. I just googled how to exit emergency mode so I decided to try it.

Comment: FYI: you are using the `./` inside a folder, please check if the directory have the prompted command before run it.